# Stop anchor element from reloading and/or scrolling to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When someone clicks the #collapseOne anchor, the page reloads with a scroll to top. I need to disable that. However, I can't change the href to anything else, as it's used for the site's functionality. Any way to either prevent the site from scrolling to top or to prevent it from reloading at all?

```
  <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
  <div class="accordion-group">
  <div class="accordion-heading">
  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseOne">
    Collapsible Group Item #1
  </a>
 </div>
 <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-body collapse in">
  <div class="accordion-inner">
    Anim pariatur cliche...
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="accordion-group">
  <div class="accordion-heading">
  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapseTwo">
    Collapsible Group Item #2
  </a>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Here's the JavaScript. It's Twitter Bootstrap.

```
!function ($) {

"use strict"; // jshint ;_;


/* COLLAPSE PUBLIC CLASS DEFINITION
 * ================================ */

var Collapse = function (element, options) {
this.$element = $(element)
this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.collapse.defaults, options)

if (this.options.parent) {
  this.$parent = $(this.options.parent)
}

this.options.toggle && this.toggle()
}

Collapse.prototype = {

constructor: Collapse

, dimension: function () {
  var hasWidth = this.$element.hasClass('width')
  return hasWidth ? 'width' : 'height'
}

, show: function () {
  var dimension
    , scroll
    , actives
    , hasData

  if (this.transitioning || this.$element.hasClass('in')) return

  dimension = this.dimension()
  scroll = $.camelCase(['scroll', dimension].join('-'))
  actives = this.$parent && this.$parent.find('> .accordion-group > .in')

  if (actives && actives.length) {
    hasData = actives.data('collapse')
    if (hasData && hasData.transitioning) return
    actives.collapse('hide')
    hasData || actives.data('collapse', null)
  }

  this.$element[dimension](0)
  this.transition('addClass', $.Event('show'), 'shown')
  $.support.transition && this.$element[dimension](this.$element[0][scroll])
 }

, hide: function () {
  var dimension
  if (this.transitioning || !this.$element.hasClass('in')) return
  dimension = this.dimension()
  this.reset(this.$element[dimension]())
  this.transition('removeClass', $.Event('hide'), 'hidden')
  this.$element[dimension](0)
}

, reset: function (size) {
  var dimension = this.dimension()

  this.$element
    .removeClass('collapse')
    [dimension](size || 'auto')
    [0].offsetWidth

  this.$element[size !== null ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('collapse')

  return this
}

, transition: function (method, startEvent, completeEvent) {
  var that = this
    , complete = function () {
        if (startEvent.type == 'show') that.reset()
        that.transitioning = 0
        that.$element.trigger(completeEvent)
      }

  this.$element.trigger(startEvent)

  if (startEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

  this.transitioning = 1

  this.$element[method]('in')

  $.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('collapse') ?
    this.$element.one($.support.transition.end, complete) :
    complete()
}

, toggle: function () {
  this[this.$element.hasClass('in') ? 'hide' : 'show']()
}

}


/* COLLAPSE PLUGIN DEFINITION
* ========================== */

var old = $.fn.collapse

$.fn.collapse = function (option) {
return this.each(function () {
  var $this = $(this)
    , data = $this.data('collapse')
    , options = $.extend({}, $.fn.collapse.defaults, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)
  if (!data) $this.data('collapse', (data = new Collapse(this, options)))
  if (typeof option == 'string') data[option]()
})
}

$.fn.collapse.defaults = {
toggle: true
}

$.fn.collapse.Constructor = Collapse


/* COLLAPSE NO CONFLICT
* ==================== */

$.fn.collapse.noConflict = function () {
$.fn.collapse = old
return this
}


/* COLLAPSE DATA-API
* ================= */

$(document).on('click.collapse.data-api', '[data-toggle=collapse]', function (e) {
var $this = $(this), href
  , target = $this.attr('data-target')
    || e.preventDefault()
    || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '') //strip for ie7
  , option = $(target).data('collapse') ? 'toggle' : $this.data()
$this[$(target).hasClass('in') ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('collapsed')
$(target).collapse(option)
})

}(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Your JS code please :). Might be missing a `e.preventDefault();` in your click event. The click event code'll do.

Comment: Just added the JS. It's Twitter Bootstrap. I would have copied less code, but I'm not sure which section you'd need to see.

Comment: doesnt matter what you use,when you want to disable the natural behavious of a link..always use `javascript:void(0)`..check the answer,good luk with your project

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a.accordion-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    // whatever other code this click event needs to run here...
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

`e` is the event object, calling `preventDefault` method stops it from its normal behavior (in this case reloading the page and resetting scroll position).  You may need to combine this with your existing click handling code for it to work properly (you didn't provide all your code obviously).

`return false` also works similar to `e.preventDefault()` (actually it just runs `e.preventDefault` and also `e.stopPropagation` which prevents click event propagation to parent elements in the DOM).

Answer (score 0):

**javascript:void(0)**

I would always recommend you,not to use `preventDefault`(cross browser issues).
`return false` too is not as reliant.

i have had the same problem in past.I resorted to this as it Works in all browser!!!

```
$('#my_herf_id').on('click', function() {
       // code..
    $("#my_herf_id").attr('href','javascript:void(0)');
}
```

Comment: He specifically stated that the `href` value cannot change. Otherwise yes this is a more reliable way to prevent default anchor behavior than `preventDefault` or `return false`.

Comment: nothing changes here...op gets what he wants..it does the same what prevent default does to href..100% surity

Comment: I tried but not luck. Did I do this right?     
<script> 
  
  $('collapseOne').on('click', function() {
       // code..
    $("#collapseOne").attr('href','javascript:void(0)');
}
  
</script>

Comment: @user2635166:provide it to a link`s id,you havent assigned an id to <a `class="accordion-toggle" `...with  `$('collapseOne')` you are selecting div.not a link..this will work 100%

Comment: Couldn't figure out the right place to put it. Guess I'm not experienced enough even with the right answer.. Thanks anyway!